# Is the Legendre transform of a differentiable function also differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f=f(x)$ be a real-valued differentiable convex function. The Legendre transform $g$ of $f$ is a function of $p$ defined by:
$$g(p) = \max_{x}(px - f(x))$$

**Question:** Is $g$ differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

Not always. Take for example a linear function $f(x)=ax+b$ in one dimension. Then $f^*(p)=+\infty$ for $p\neq a$ and $f^*(a)=b$. If $f$ is differentiable and strictly convex then $f^*$ is convex and differentiable.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! By strictly convex you mean $f''(x)>0$? Do you know how to prove your claim?

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152432/smoothness-and-hessian-of-convex-conjugate-legendre-transform?rq=1